# Spring Security SAML2 multiple IDPs configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-security-saml2

I am trying to configure multiple idps via `RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository` using spring security 5.3
This is my application.yaml config

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          idpokta:
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: http://<url>
              sso-url: https://<url>
              verification:
                credentials:
                  - certificate-location: "classpath:saml/okta.cert"
              signing:
                credentials:
                  certificate: |
                    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                    MIIDpDCC...
                    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
                  private-key: |
                    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
                    MIIEvQIBA....

                    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

          idponelogin:
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: https://<url>
              sso-url: https://<url>
              verification:
                credentials:
                  - certificate-location: "classpath:saml/onelogin.cert"
            signing:
              credentials:
                certificate: |
                  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                  MIID/z...
                  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
                private-key: |
                  -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
                  MIpoi...

                  -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

my login controller is defined as follows:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    private final RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingParties;

    // ... 

   @GetMapping("/login")
  public void login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String registrationId = request.getParameter("idp");
    RelyingPartyRegistration relyingParty = this.relyingParties
            .findByRegistrationId(registrationId);
    if (relyingParty == null) {
      response.setStatus(401);
    } else {
      response.sendRedirect("/saml2/authenticate/" + registrationId);
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**
my relyingParty has the provider details but I think the fact that my `assertionConsumerServiceUrl` is defaulting to `{baseUrl}/login/saml2/sso/{registrationId}` and my `localEntityIdTemplate` = {baseUrl}/saml2/service-provider-metadata/{registrationId}` is causing it the problem. How do I add the sp info in my yaml file? or Am I doing this completely wrong?

**Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to do the same thing. The API doesn't seem to be well thought through. If you try to use auto configuration spring boot feature the only way I found is to exclude this configuration

```
Saml2RelyingPartyRegistrationConfiguration
```

and provide your own class for that.

Since all of that is package local, you have to bring pretty much entire package

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.saml2
```

to your own application first disabling the one from spring altogether.

You will end up with

```
CustomRegistrationConfiguredCondition
CustomSaml2LoginConfiguration
CustomSaml2RelyingPartyAutoConfiguration
CustomSaml2RelyingPartyRegistrationConfiguration
```

at the very least.
Make sure the references between the classes are updated too.

Now, you need to update the following method in the CustomSaml2RelyingPartyRegistrationConfiguration:

```
    private RelyingPartyRegistration asRegistration(String id, Registration properties) {
        RelyingPartyRegistration.Builder builder = RelyingPartyRegistration.withRegistrationId(id);
        builder.assertionConsumerServiceUrlTemplate(
                "{baseUrl}" + Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.DEFAULT_FILTER_PROCESSES_URI);
        builder.idpWebSsoUrl(properties.getIdentityprovider().getSsoUrl());
        builder.remoteIdpEntityId(properties.getIdentityprovider().getEntityId());
        builder.localEntityIdTemplate("template_you_like");
        builder.credentials((credentials) -> credentials.addAll(asCredentials(properties)));
        return builder.build();
    }
```

Alternatively, you can also copy Saml2RelyingPartyProperties to your project and add all necessary fields there. This way you'll be able to set properties in yaml or properties file. Don't forget to use those values in asRegistration method mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you posted, it seems that `assertionConsumerServiceUrl="{baseUrl}/login/saml2/sso/{registrationId}"` at runtime (so the bindings are not working). In my experience, I had it working by replacing `baseUrl` and `registrationId` with the actual values (bypassing the placeholders).

E.g.: `http://localhost:8080/login/saml2/sso/idpokta`

The same goes for `localEntityIdTemplate`: `http://localhost:8080/saml2/service-provider-metadata/idpokta`